# Getting response object of a servlet in its superclass

Tags: java, servlets, exception, http-error

I call `method1` of `servlet1` from `service()` of `servlet2`. I want to throw `sendError(5xx)` from `servlet1`. But it needs the response object of `servlet2` which I am not passing. Any other method to throw the HTTP status codes?

```
 public class servlet2 extends servlet1{

        public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        }
        }

        public abstract class servlet1 extends HTTPServlet{

         public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        }
public boolean method1()
{
return true;
}
        }
```

Comment: How do you call the one servlet from the other? And why are you not passing the objects that you need?

Comment: 'servlet2' extends 'servlet1'. 'method1()' in 'servlet1' will be called from 'servlet2'. 'sendError()' needs to be called in 'method1()'. In 'method1()' signature 'request,response' object can not be passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke a custom `method1` of servlet1, from servlet2, then the servlet1 don't act as a real Servlet, but as a normal object. In that case, the servlet1 don't have any HttpServletResponse to wich send an error.

The normal way to dispatch the control from one servlet to another, is using a RequestDispatcher. For example, execute this sentence from servlet2:

```
getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("servlet1").forward(request, response);
```

In servlet1, you receive the request in the `service` method, with receive as a parameter an HttpServletResponse, which you can use to send the error.

Comment: Yes this approach works fine when we have response object.I do not get the response object in servlet1. Is there any other method we can handle this?

Comment: Why you don't have the HttpServletResponse object in servlet1? If you use the dispatcher, like the example I wrote, then the dispatcher invokes the `service` method in the servlet1, with `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` parameters. Calling directly a servlet from other servlet, without using a dispathcer, is incorrect. And there's **NO** way to send an error without a `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: Yes with dispacher it works fine...